# Bypass Office Web App and always use Coauthoring?

Tags: 2013, co-authoring

I believe we're on SharePoint Server 2013. I'm a user running Firefox 64-bit.

I'm looking for a one-click solution to opening a Word doc or PowerPoint in my desktop application, instead of right-clicking, clicking Edit, waiting for the web app to load, and clicking Edit in the PowerPoint Web App. I also want to make sure the Coauthoring feature is working.

When **Open in the client application** from Site Settings | Advanced is enabled, clicking a file will give me a prompt to open or download the file. Coauthoring does not work from these locally downloaded files. Clicking Edit will continue to open it in the browser web app, even if **Open in client application** is working.

I find the Office Web Apps are clunky and missing crucial features I need, so I want to use the Web App 0% of the time. This is driving me crazy because I feel like I used to have it work the way I want, but something changed and I always have to go through the web app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to activate '**Open Documents in Client Applications by Default**' feature under the **site collection feature** and also the Open in the client application under list setting.  [Have a look at this](https://www.syvantis.com/blog/sharepoint-online-is-opening-my-documents-in-the-online-version-of-office-how-can-i-make-them-open-in-my-desktop-applications)

I tested this and it is working as expected i.e. documents are opening in the client application rather than in the browser.

Comment: There's a known bug in SP 2013 where Firefox and Chrome completely ignores that setting.  We've tried a CU after the supposed fix was put in place but never managed to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks you. Greg's identified the bug I am experiencing, and I've confirmed that it works in IE as expected. It's unfortunate how many bugs and broken SharePoint features plague Firefox/Chrome users.